# Can e-mail (SMTP) be sent directly over RS-232

Tags: linux, email, serial-port, smtp, embedded

I'm in somewhat of an odd situation here. I'm looking to send SMTP e-mails from a remote embedded system which is directly connected to an iridium modem into a local server. The current system sends files in chunks of data and I don't know exactly how this would work with e-mail. I was thinking of using mutt to send attachments (.wav or .jpeg files), but again I don't know if this works without direct internet access. If anyone has any idea if this is possible, please let me know.

Edit: I'm using RUDICS communication, not a SBD modem

Thanks

Comment: @old_timer : An _Iridium modem_ is a device for sending data via the Iridium communications satellite system.  Data is sent via Iridium's Short Burst Data (SBD) service - it is not a modem in the "dial-up modem" sense.

Comment: @old_timer :  I am not talking about _"dial-up Internet"_, just "dial-up modem".  Iridium SDB modems are not "dial-up", they connect only to the Iridium network, and data is forwarded to an address assigned to the specific Iridium account - it arrives as email or HTTP; so the answer to the question is "yes" but not for the reasons you state; no SLIP or PPP are required and no direct connection to the Internet is possible.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @Clifford - The information on the Iridium network is interesting. We briefly studied it in college years ago. But where are you making the leap the OP's question is about the Iridium network? The best I can tell its not part of the question. My apologies if I am mis-parsing something.

Comment: @jww : What else would you connect an _" an iridium modem"_ to? (first sentence).  Elsewhere the OP has commented on the fact that he is using the RUDICS service rather then SDB; I have suggested that he update the question to include that information as it is probably essential information.  However I have also suggested that his service provider may be the best source of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Iridium Short Burst Data (SBD) service sends burst of less that 2Kb at a time and the revenue model for Iridium service might make sending audio and image data very expensive.

Nonetheless messages are converted by the Iridium network to be delivered in email format or over HTTP to a pre-configured address.  The address to which data is sent is assigned to your Iridium service subscription, not stored or configurable by the sender.  You can of course forward the received data to any desired destination.

You can get a direct Internet connection using an Iridium phone (https://www.iridium.com/services/details/iridium-direct-internet); but that is an expensive and bulky solution.

Comment: I see. We actually are using RUDICS, not SBD if that makes sense. Okay, guess we'll stick to just sending reports of file creations instead of actual files. I've seen the iridium phone plans but like you said I've read the reviews, it seems bulky and the quality just isn't there yet

Comment: @D.Jamieson : That is probably information that should be in the question - as you can see most answers and comments focus on the "modem" term and have assumed you are talking about a dial-up PSTN modem.  I am not familiar with RUDICS, but suggest that your service provider would be best placed to answer your question; they are in the business of selling bandwidth it is in their interests for you to purchase as much as possible!

Comment: @D.Jamieson : [This whitepaper](http://www.stratosglobal.com/~/media/documents/irid/public/irid_whitepaper_satellitedataservices.pdf) lists _"Email – Sending and receiving of email using custom applications software"_ as a "typical application" or RUDICS; however from by brief reading of the document, the e-mail forwarding would be implemented at "host application" rather then the "remote application" - that is you get data in whatever form you define and what the application does with it is up to you.  It also mentions FTP in the "typical application" list, which may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but somewhat complex. You would need to setup a PPP connection with the modem and then email would be able to flow across the serial line to the other server.

Comment: Not for an Iridium SBD modem.  He is not talking about a dial-up modem.  For Iridium SBD the data is already delivered as e-mail to a predefined address.  It is entirely unsuited to delivering .wav or .jpeg (at least ant any reasonable cost).

Comment: I actually have already set up the PPP more as a concept exercise. Guess that won' work either though. we're actually using RUDICS and not the SBD currently.